# JMS message sent to Artemis queue from JBoss 7.4.2 does not get delivered to Camel route using JMS component

Tags: java, jboss, apache-camel, jms, activemq-artemis

A JMS message sent to a dynamic queue on Artemis server in JBoss EAP 7.4.2 does not get delivered to Camel route listener using JMS component

**Camel route:**

```java
from("jms:queue:XXX")
    .process("xyz")
    .end();
```

**Environment:**

Camel route(s) deployed on **JBoss EAP 7.4.2** receiving JMS messages from three external **ActiveMQ Artemis 2.16** servers with support for failovers/HA using default protocol, using **Apache Camel 2.25.4**.

**ActiveMQ Artemis resource adapter settings:**

```xml
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
        <remote-connector name="netty-artemis-sharedinternal-1" socket-binding="artemis-sharedinternal-1"/>
        <remote-connector name="netty-artemis-sharedinternal-2" socket-binding="artemis-sharedinternal-2"/>
        <remote-connector name="netty-artemis-sharedinternal-3" socket-binding="artemis-sharedinternal-3"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="org.apache.activemq" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="netty-artemis-sharedinternal-1 netty-artemis-sharedinternal-2 netty-artemis-sharedinternal-3" ha="true" failover-on-initial-connection="true" use-topology-for-load-balancing="true" transaction="none" user="user" password="password" min-pool-size="24" use-auto-recovery="true" max-pool-size="256" initial-connect-attempts="2" statistics-enabled="true" enable-amq1-prefix="false">
            <inbound-config use-jndi="false" rebalance-connections="true" setup-attempts="2" setup-interval="5000"/>
        </pooled-connection-factory>
        ...
```

**Relevant log entry from server:**

```
2023-07-21 11:19:11,610 TRACE [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.BindingsImpl] Routing message CoreMessage[messageID=19732099994,durable=false,userID=f1f92ea4-27d9-11ee-8ee7-005056b75c06,priority=4, timestamp=Fri Jul 21 11:19:11 EDT 2023,expiration=Fri Jul 28 11:19:11 EDT 2023, durable=false, address=NationalAdAssetNotificationQueue,size=1680,properties=TypedProperties[__AMQ_CID=4adf63bc-27d7-11ee-8ee7-005056b75c06,_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=1]]@980219731 on binding=BindingsImpl [name=NationalAdAssetNotificationQueue] current context::RoutingContextImpl(Address=XXXQueue, routingType=ANYCAST, PreviousAddress=XXXQueue previousRoute:ANYCAST, reusable=null, version=0)
```

On the other hand a similar message sent to the same queue by a standalone Java application gets delivered to the Camel route in JBoss

```
2023-07-21 11:22:02,361 TRACE [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.BindingsImpl] Routing message CoreMessage[messageID=20646163200,durable=false,userID=57bd2005-27da-11ee-92bb-025041000001,priority=4, timestamp=Fri Jul 21 11:22:02 EDT 2023,expiration=Fri Jul 28 11:22:02 EDT 2023, durable=false, address=XXXQueue,size=1538,properties=TypedProperties[__AMQ_CID=578aec72-27da-11ee-92bb-025041000001,_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=1]]@654187160 on binding=BindingsImpl [name=XXXQueue] current context::RoutingContextImpl(Address=NationalAdAssetNotificationQueue, routingType=ANYCAST, PreviousAddress=null previousRoute:null, reusable=null, version=0)
```

The only difference(s) between the 2 log entries is that the one that fails has:

```
PreviousAddress=XXXQueue previousRoute:ANYCAST
```

and the one that works has:

```
PreviousAddress=null previousRoute:null
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old release of ActiveMQ Artemis? The current release is 2.30.0. Version 2.16.0 was released almost 3 years ago now.

Comment: Is Camel using the `pooled-connection-factory`?

Comment: Is the problem that the message isn't delivered to the queue at all or is it that the message is successfully delivered to the queue but the Camel route is unable to consume it? In the problematic case what is sending the message? Is it another Camel route?

Comment: **Answers to questions:** The choice of ActiveMQ Artemis is/was a Management decision. Camel is using pooled-connection-factory. The "problematic" messages do show up on the queue, but do not get picked up and eventually expire. The Camel route listeners do not pick up these messages. The problematic messages are sent using plain vanilla Java code that looks up the ConnectionFactory from the InitialContext using its JNDI name, then creates a connection and message and then sends it.

Comment: So the consumer count on the queue is > 0 and the message count is also > 0, but the messages are not consumed? What is the delivering count at this time?

Comment: In your description you said "a standalone Java application" sends messages which are consumed normally, but you also have "plain vanilla Java code" which sends messages which are *not* consumed? Are there any differences between these applications? Can you share the code?

Comment: Sorry it took a month to revisit this issue. Apparently the messages do get to the server(s), but do not get distributed to JMS consumers that are awaiting messages, but are connected to different server. This is a distribution issue so I will post a new question and close this one. Thx